# WooCommerce - shop page conditional by category

Tags: wordpress, conditional-statements, woocommerce

How can I have a conditional which checks the product's category in the WooCommerce's main shop window? For example:

```
if($product_category == 'service') {
    echo 'alpha';
} else {
    echo 'beta';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (is_product_category('slug')) { // Example: Shirts
   echo 'alpha, hello im a shirt';
} else {
   echo 'beta';
}
```

Comment: Hi MrRoman, thanks for the reply. Your code echoes 'beta' for all the product categories. Can you please post the source of your code, i.e. where did you find out about 'is_product_category' conditional?

Comment: **A product category page**

`is_product_category()`
    Returns true when viewing a product category archive.

`is_product_category( 'shirts' )`
    When the product category page for the ‘shirts’ category is being displayed.

`is_product_category( array( 'shirts', 'games' ) )`
    When the product category page for the ‘shirts’ or ‘games’ category is being displayed.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Well, that's not what I asked for. I need code that will add certain code to only products of a specified category when viewing the Shop page, not a category archive page.